# GH Action asks for authentication on npm install

Tags: node.js, github, npm, github-actions

There is a public repository on github with its corresponding package on npm, both are public. In previous buildings, a *GitHub Action* was publishing the package every time a new commit was merged on `main` branch.

The issue now is that the *workflow* is not working because *npm install* fails since it is asking for authentication.

This is the error stack:

```
Run npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2021-02-06T03_46_34_194Z-debug.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

These are the dependencies:

```
 "dependencies": {
        "amqplib": "^0.6.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
        "cors": "^2.8.4",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-fileupload": "^1.1.4",
        "gridfs-stream": "^1.1.1",
        "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "mongoose": "^5.11.8",
        "multer": "^1.4.1",
        "redis": "^3.0.2",
        "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "^11.0.0",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^11.0.0",
        "@types/amqplib": "^0.5.17",
        "@types/body-parser": "^1.16.7",
        "@types/cors": "^2.8.3",
        "@types/express": "^4.17.9",
        "@types/gridfs-stream": "^0.5.30",
        "@types/multer": "^1.3.7",
        "@types/node": "^14.14.16",
        "@types/redis": "^2.8.6",
        "del": "^6.0.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-exec": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-string-replace": "^1.1.2",
        "husky": "^4.3.8",
        "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "typedoc": "^0.19.2",
        "typescript": "^4.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: do you have `.npmrc` file in the repository?

Comment: No, I don't have it. Is it necessary? What configuration I should use?

Comment: My understanding  is that the .npmrc file should contain `@<scope>:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

Comment: I am having the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73247706/unable-to-install-public-npm-package-from-github-package-registry-using-github-a).