# Unable to install public NPM-package from Github Package Registry using Github Actions

Tags: npm, github-actions, npm-install, github-package-registry

There is a [public NPM package](https://github.com/instacart/radium/packages/390171) in the Github Package Registry im trying to install using Github Actions.

I have added a `.npmrc` file next to my `package.json` with the line `@instacart:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`.

I have added the package to dependencies in my package.json;

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@instacart/radium": "^0.26.6"
  }
```

My Github Actions workflow is as follows;

```
name: Install

on: push

jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - run: npm install
```

---

I am able to run `npm install` locally without any problem, but the Github Actions workflow fails;

```
> Run npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
npm ERR! If you were trying to login, change your password, create an
npm ERR! authentication token or enable two-factor authentication then
npm ERR! that means you likely typed your password in incorrectly.
npm ERR! Please try again, or recover your password at:
npm ERR!     https://www.npmjs.com/forgot
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you were doing some other operation then your saved credentials are
npm ERR! probably out of date. To correct this please try logging in again with:
npm ERR!     npm login

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2022-08-05T09_29_15_323Z-debug-0.log
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Why is this error appearing? Why is it working fine locally, but not in the Github Actions workflow? Why is it asking for login credentials when the package is public?

Any help is much appreciated:)

Comment: You don't need an `.npmrc` file for public packages in the default registry.

Comment: It is not hosted at the npm registry, but at Github Packages

Comment: it's here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@instacart/radium ..?

Comment: The actual package is not important, it is just an example. Pretend it is only available in the Github Package Registry.

Comment: gotcha. the docs say you always need to authenticate? https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A personal access token with the `read:packages` scope is required to download and install public packages from the GitHub npm registry. See [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/about-permissions-for-github-packages#about-scopes-and-permissions-for-package-registries) for details.

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/learn-github-packages/introduction-to-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages) have been updated. "You need an access token to publish, install, and delete private, internal, and public packages."

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `GITHUB_ENV` in your step env (the `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret is automatically filled by GitHub):

```
jobs:
  install:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16
      - name: Install dependencies
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        run: npm install
```

and you also need to give read permission to your repository in package settings:

[image]